# jQuery doesn't recognizes changes after .removeClass() and others

Tags: jquery, sequence, addclass

I'm fed up with a strange issue- or just regular functionality.. Either way.

I'm using the following code

```
$(function () {
    $('nav.closed').click(function () {
        console.log('time to open it');
        $(this).removeClass('closed').addClass('opened')
        $('.navBar.collapsed').removeClass('collapsed').addClass('open');
    });
    $('nav.opened').click(function () {
        console.log('time to close it');
        $(this).removeClass('opened').addClass('closed')
        $('.navBar.open').removeClass('open').addClass('collapsed');
    });
});
```

to open the nav bar when it's closed- and close it when it's opened. I'm using the 'open' and 'close' classes to 'see' whether it is opened or not and based upon that fire the correct functionality.

However.. *Let's say it's closed on default*

When I click on the nav bar (which is closed) it removes `.closed` and adds `.opened` and logs `Time to open it`. When I now click it for the second time it should remove `.opened`, add `.closed` and log `time to close it`. However, it thinks it still has the old classes and thus does nothing, but logs `time to open it`, even when it's opened already..

Why does jQuery/my script doesn't experience the changes and keeps just as the page is loaded..?

Edit: I'm trying to achieve [this nav animation](https://dribbble.com/shots/1706861-Top-Menu-Animation?list=searches&tag=mobile_interface&offset=59), although a bit different. *Click on main nav bar to open hidden navigation*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use $('.nav').click and write an if statement with hasClass inside. It's because jQuery only append the click function when the DOM was generated. You don't have any opened divs here. The correct solution should be something like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('nav').click(function () {
        if($(this).hasClass("closed")) {
            console.log('time to open it');
            $(this).removeClass('closed').addClass('opened');
            $('.navBar.collapsed').removeClass('collapsed').addClass('open');
        }
        else if($(this).hasClass("opened")) {
            console.log('time to close it');
            $(this).removeClass('opened').addClass('closed');
            $('.navBar.open').removeClass('open').addClass('collapsed');
        }
    });
});
```

But it's much cleaner if you do it like so:

```
$(function () {
    $('nav').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("opened").toggleClass("closed");
        $('.navBar').toggleClass("open").toggleClass("collapsed");
    });
});
```

Comment: First for my own interpretation: So jQuery only reads and remembers how the DOM/Page has loaded and does not recognizes changes, such as addClass, remove or add commands? Secondly. Bravo. Both Toggle and if.HasClass() are great solutions I hadn't thought of. Indeed. The second, my preference, is much cleaner. Thank you!

Comment: jQuery can track the canges of a DOM element, but $(function(){ // This will be only executed on DOM ready; }); You can check the classes of any div with a variable reference like $(this), or any javascript var where you stored the jQuery object before. But when your script runs, the click event will be appended to all .nav.opened objects. The number of these  are zero (when the page loads). You can check it by appending alert($('.nav.opened").length+$('.navBar.open').length); to the end of your jQuery code.